# collection_select (Select) in Rails not changing values on databse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have the collection_select working fine, however i have :include_blank option, and I want when the include_blank value is selected, to delete the ID from the database and leave it null.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this with the link mentioned below

`<%= f.select(:user_id,  [['Team', 0]] + User.all.collect { |p| [p.email, p.id]}) %>`